# Where was the planet inhabited by "the Giants" located relative to Earth?

Tags: land-of-the-giants

Simply put, **where exactly is the planet inhabited by "*the Giants*" that the crew of the *Spindrift* crash-land on?** I haven't been able to figure that out from watching the show.

Comment: The wikipedia article suggests that its location is highly unclear. It's near Earth, somewhere in Earth's solar system or possibly through a wormhole or in another dimension; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_of_the_Giants

Answer (score 1):

If you think that *Star Trek* or *Babylon 5* seems vague and inaccurate about the "geography" of outer space, you haven't seen anything yet until you watch Irwin Allen movies and TV series.  If you were more familiar with Irwin Allen movies and TV series you wouldn't ask "where exactly" any of his planets were.

I have watched many of the episodes and don't remember seeing any star maps or hearing any discussion of the location of *Jotunheim* - my private name for the planet full of giants.

The thought has occurred to me that possibly the heroes's craft somehow went through a space and/or time warp that caused the vehicle and passengers to shirk in size and then land somewhere on Earth and think they must be on a different planet because everything is so large.  But I can't remember if there was any hint that the producers might be thinking of such a twist.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's an alternate Earth; the Spindrift veers through a time-space warp in 1983 but winds up on an alternate version of the Earth circa 1969-70, present-day when the show airs.

Things have gone horribly wrong for the passengers and crew of the Spindrift; not only they're stranded in a very hostile world, but also on a different timeframe. The alternate Earth, though its name is kept hidden from the audience, is a parallax version; apparently it's under a global, totalitarian police-state regime, with some of its culture resembling Earth's present-day North America.

Some of the giants technology pre-dates the Spindrift; and yet in some episodes there are force fields, advanced sub-atomic particles research, and even some of the giants have achieved miniaturization.

But generally, the giants speak english, drive cars, use electricity and a money-driven economy. One of the eerieness of the show to me as I remember, was the sluggishness and ominous nature of the giant society. Seems like a very opresive regime. In one episode, even an underground opposition is mentioned.

But Irwin Allen was a master in merely hinting at whose world is the show depicting. It could be Earth, but ANOTHER Earth.

And although initially unaware, the giants ALSO suspect something's wrong. Rumours of this "Little People" abound (sightings and testimonies) so the giants' authorities began to investigate and order to the public to report on the matter IMMEDIATELY.

It was very intelligent sci-fi, with the necessary dash of silly fun to make for children's entertainment; let's not forget the amazing work the network did with the limited FX available at the time. On an industry driven by ratings over tried and proven formulas, is still amazing that fantastic shows like this were produced. Thanks for the opportunity to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

My take is that Land of the Giants was in an alternate universe; version of Earth, but not in what we know as the United States. There were similarities, but many differences.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).